# How to display jquery range slider input fields inside td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery range slider in my page. The range slider displays it's range from 0 to 100. What i need is, only this range should be displayed inside td tags like

```
<td><input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="0" type="range"></td>
```

but it's not working in this manner.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/k5ywZ/)**

Comment: Your fiddle has no table and this question doesn't have all your code. Please correct that.

Comment: Be more specific, I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: @j08691 i didn't use table because if i take this slider in table and ranges in td it's not showing anything.

Comment: @JoséBarbosa : i m using this for responsive design. so according to my requirement the left & right side ranges maintain some distance from the slider. So i need to take slider and ranges inside td tags. that's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The rangeslider is already responsive in that it automatically re-sizes with screen width. If all you want is to control the distance between the slider track and the left and right inputs, you can do this with CSS as follows:

```
.ui-rangeslider .ui-rangeslider-sliders {
    margin-left: 86px;
    margin-right: 86px;
}
```

In your fiddle, the default margin is 68px. I have increased it to 86px.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/k5ywZ/2/)**

NOTE: if you want different margins at different screen widths, you can use media queries in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
     </div>
      <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%;"><label>Rangeslider:</label></td>
                 <td>
                     <div data-role="rangeslider">
                         <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100"  value="0" type="range">
                          <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="100" type="range"></div></td>
             </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```